# Getting error TypeError: 'SQLModelMetaclass' object is not iterable

Tags: python, fastapi, sqlmodel

I have a fastapi project using SQLModel that has JWT auth active.  I have a registration endpoint and am trying to return a subset of the user record when a post to the registration endpoint is successful. I seem to be able to return the 'User' model which is tied to an actual table but I don't want to return the password hash so I created a new model called 'SensitiveUser' not tied to any table with the password removed.  However, when I try to use this model and return the data from the endpoint I get the error "TypeError: 'SQLModelMetaclass' object is not iterable". Any insight on why this is happening is appreciated.  I'm struggling to find this exact issue elsewhere online. Thanks.

Repo:

```
# Return all users.
def select_all_users():
    with Session(rms_engine) as session:
        statement = select(User)
        res = session.exec(statement).all()
        return res

# Returns a specific user record.
def find_user(name):
    with Session(rms_engine) as session:
        statement = select(User).where(User.username == name)
        return session.exec(statement).first()

# Returns a specific user record withou password information.
def find_sensitive_user(name):
    with Session(rms_engine) as session:
        statement = select(SensitiveUser).where(SensitiveUser.username == name)
        return session.exec(statement).first()
```

Models:

```
class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    username: str
    password: str = Field(max_length=256, min_length=6)
    email: EmailStr
    created_at: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    is_admin: bool = False

class SensitiveUser(SQLModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    email: str
    created_at: datetime.datetime
```

The code below does work but returns more info than I want, namely the password:

```
@user_router.post('/register', status_code=201, tags=['users'], description='Register a new user')
def register(user: UserInput):
    users = select_all_users()
    if any(x.username == user.username for x in users):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Username is taken')
    hashed_pwd = auth_handler.get_password_hash(user.password)
    u = User(username=user.username, password=hashed_pwd, email=user.email, is_admin=user.is_admin)
    rms_session.add(u)
    rms_session.commit()
    stored_user = find_user(user.username) 
    return stored_user
```

The code below returns the "TypeError: 'SQLModelMetaclass' object is not iterable" error:

```
@user_router.post('/register', status_code=201, tags=['users'], description='Register a new user')
def register(user: UserInput):
    users = select_all_users()
    if any(x.username == user.username for x in users):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Username is taken')
    hashed_pwd = auth_handler.get_password_hash(user.password)
    u = User(username=user.username, password=hashed_pwd, email=user.email, is_admin=user.is_admin)
    rms_session.add(u)
    rms_session.commit()
    stored_user = find_sensitive_user(user.username) # <--- Error Occurs Here
    return stored_user
```

Comment: Probably the `JSON` encoder needs to iterate over the object that you're returning (a `SQLModelMetaclass`), which causes the error. Try transforming the result into a `dict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you cannot select an object that has not been mapped to the database's table, and SensitiveUser's objects are not!
You should extend your `User` class to produce `SensitiveUser`s, like this:

```
class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    username: str
    password: str = Field(max_length=256, min_length=6)
    email: str
    created_at: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    is_admin: bool = False

    def to_sensitive_user(self) -> SensitiveUser:
        return SensitiveUser(id=self.id, username=self.username, 
                             email=self.email, created_at=self.created_at)
```

And then, you can use `find_user` function extended with the call to `to_sensitive_user()`, like this:

```
stored_user = find_user(user.username).to_sensitive_user()
```

Of course, here needs to be **some is-not-None checking** and `SensitiveUser` needs to be defined before `User`, as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how it worked and this cleared it up. Appreciate it.